# 1inch api - Error 500 cannot find path for [token]

Tags: ethereum

Wondering why api call to swap token to token (sUSD to ETH or WETH) is failing

curl -X GET "https://api.1inch.exchange/v3.0/1/swap?fromTokenAddress=0x6b175474e89094c44da98b954eedeac495271d0f&toTokenAddress=0x5e74c9036fb86bd7ecdcb084a0673efc32ea31cb&amount=10&fromAddress=0x52bc44d5378309ee2abf1539bf71de1b7d7be3b5&slippage=1" -H  "accept: application/json"

{
"statusCode": 500,
"message": "cannot find path for 0x5e74c9036fb86bd7ecdcb084a0673efc32ea31cb",
"error": "Internal Server Error"
}

The token is listed in the /tokens api call..

API Playground:
https://api.1inch.exchange/swagger/ethereum/#/Swap/SwapFactoryController_getQuote

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is a question for 1inch support